# Docusign API - Unable to fetch User Permission Type

Tags: vb.net, api, soap, docusignapi

i integrate docusign api service in my application via SOAP, i already validate the used but now i want to know that, how can i get user permission type.. means i have more than one user attached with same account id and i want to check whether user have sender permission, viewer permission or admin permission..
Kindly let me know via which service i get that information
i try to get information from "Account Manager Service" but i received error message stated "invalid user or user is not administrator"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get user settings of an account member you need to make the

```
GetMemberSettings()
```

api call.  You can view the details of the call and what it returns here:

https://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/AccountManagement.asmx?op=GetMemberSettings